# Яндекс Карты и Очень Много Меток

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Мы в проекте меняем Google Maps на Яндекс Карты. И есть у нас карта, которая показывает 20,000 кликабельных точек. Google Maps несколько напрягаясь, но все таки рисует их. Яндекс Карты просто ни в какую.

Что можно сделать? Если конечно можно.

Comment: Разумнее всего, на мой взгляд, разделить точки по категориям. Так, по крайней мере, у вас есть шансы на спасение проекта.

Comment: Проект спасать не надо, а вот использование Яндекс Карт под вопросом. Будет себя плохо вести, вернемся на Google Maps.